# MIPS decoding a branch instruction from machine-code to assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, disassembly, opcode

I am little bit confuse about following machine code
0001 1001 0110 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010
this is binary code for machine language and I translated to mips 32 bit instruction.

```
000110 01011 00000 0000 0000 0000 0010

blez   $t3,        2
```

I am not sure if I translated correctly.

I am not sure why the immediate value is 2 instead of address of target location.

Comment: MIPS `b` instructions use a relative displacement for the target (i.e. relative to PC).  It's left-shifted., though, which you left out.  https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Mips/addr.html

Comment: okay so if that instruction is in address of 1122334C, adding 8 to the current address  is destination? therefore, it should jump to 11223354?

Answer (score 1):

I am getting a different offset than you are so re-check either the bits you gave us or your math.

```
.word 0x19600002
nop
nop
nop
nop
.word 0x19600002

mips-elf-as so.s -o so.o
mips-elf-objdump -D so.o


00000000 <.text>:
   0:   19600002    blez    $11,0xc
   4:   00000000    nop
    ...
  14:   19600002    blez    $11,0x20
```

Is there an assumed/implied 0x4 added to the offset?

Comment: MIPS branch offsets are relative to the end of the branch instruction.  (i.e. the usual `PC+=4` happens *as well* as adding the branch displacement.)  The OP isn't technically *wrong* for showing just the relative displacement, it's just a matter of how it's interpreted.  (BTW, x86 is like this too: relative branches and RIP-relative addressing modes are relative to the end of the instruction.)  +1 for throwing the machine code at a disassembler to check the whole thing.

Comment: not just those arm, and others are the same, very common actually, just helping the op out to show there is more than just the encoded immediate that comes into play.

Comment: (knew the answer when I asked the question, but the OP needs to do more research, for example if you have working tools available, see what they say compared to what you have come up with)